# Theme not getting copied

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I worked on a website and it was hosted on bigrock server. But the client want me to transfer into just host. I managed to copy all the stuffs, but the theme I installed into old server is not getting copied into new justhost server. Please help me out in this one.

Answer (score 0):

more details maybe, maybe an error message or something?

But: I found it quite common for file permissions to be an issue when using straight copy/paste/move. 
When moving anything like a cms or cart with potential file permission issues, I would through cpanel/UI compress the lot and then move or copy the .zip/.tar ; On new server unzip through cpanel/UI and previous permission are intact too.

Comment: But it was a problem even before moving into new server.

Comment: So your question title has nothing to do with your dilemma